# Check if field exists in any map value

Tags: common-expression-language

I have the following structure:

```
   "my-map": {
      "my-key1": {
         "field-to-find": {}
      },
      "my-key2": {
         "field-to-find": {}
      },
      "my-key3": {}
   }
```

I want to check if `field-to-find` exists in any of the values of `my-map`. Is this possible?

Things I tried:

1. Using `my-map.exists(i, has(i.field-to-find))` -> doesn't work because `i` returns just the key, not the value of the map
2. Using `my-map.exists(i, has(my-map.i.field-to-find))` -> doesn't work because `i` is treated as a string, is there a way to reference it as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out `mymap.exists(v, has(mymap[v].fieldtofind))` works.